# How to write a decent process filter?

Tags: emacs

I'm building a program that communicates with Emacs, and one of the challenges I'm facing is writing Emacs's process filter function. Its input string is a series of s-expressions to be evaluated. Here is a sample:

```
(gimme-append-to-buffer "25 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Florissants - Scene 2. Prelude - Les Arts Florissants\n")
(gimme-append-to-buffer "26 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Florissants - Cybele: 'Je Veux Joindre' - Les Arts Florissants\n")
(gimme-append-to-buffer "27 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Florissants - Scene 3. Cybele: 'Tu T'Etonnes, Melisse' - Les Arts Florissants\n")
(gimme-append-to-buffer "28 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Florissants - Cybele: 'Que Les Plus Doux Zephyrs'. Scene 4. - Les Arts Florissants\n")
(gimme-append-to-buffer "29 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Florissants - Entree Des Nations - Les Arts Florissants\n")
(gimme-append-to-buffer "30 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Florissants - Entree Des Zephyrs - Les Arts Florissants\n")
(gimme-append-to-buffer "31 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Florissants - Choeur Des Nations' 'Que Devant Vous' - Les Arts Florissants\n")
(gimme-append-to-buffer "32 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Florissants - Atys: 'Indigne Que Je Suis' - Les Arts Florissants\n")
(gimme-append-to-buffer "33 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Florissants - Reprise Du Choeur Des Nations : 'Que Devant Nous' - Les Arts Florissants\n")
(gimme-append-to-buffer "34 - William Christie dir, Les Arts Flor*emphasized text*issants - Reprise De L'Air Des Zephyrs - Les Arts Florissants\n")
```

The first problem that I've faced is that the string is somehow not fully formed when the function is so called, so writing something like `(mapcar 'eval (format "(%s)" input-string))` won't work.

To deal with this first problem, I was using a loop. The full function I wrote is:

```
 (defun eval-all-sexps (s)
   (loop for x = (ignore-errors (read-from-string s))
          then (ignore-errors (read-from-string (substring s position)))
          while x
          summing (or (cdr x) 0) into position
          doing (eval (car x))))
```

Now the second problem that showed up is that the function is called twice with a somewhat large input, first with valid but partial content, then with what looks like pieces of the remaining data.

To solve this problem, I'm considering using a junk variable to hold up what remains from a loop and then concatenating it to the input of the next call, but I was wondering if you guys have any other suggestions on how to deal with such a problem more elegantly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what I do in a shell mode I use.
I look for a special end-of-record string in the process output, to know when the output is complete.  Until then I concat the chunks.

```
(defun my-shell-exec-filter (process result)
  (let ((end-of-result (string-match my-shell-end-of-record-string result)))
    (if (and end-of-result
             (numberp end-of-result)
             (> end-of-result 0))
        (setq my-shell-reply 
              (concat my-shell-reply
                      (substring (substring result 0 end-of-result) 0 -1)))

      (progn
        (setq my-shell-reply (concat my-shell-reply result))
        (accept-process-output process my-shell-exec-timeout 5)))))
```

This isn't quite right because the end-of-record string can be split across multiple invocations of that filter fn.  So to be correct, it ought to concat first, then check for a match.  But anyway you get the idea.

Also it recurses, and because of that, for very very long input, it can incur a stack overflow exception.  So it definitely is not as clean as I would like.

The thing is kicked off with

```
      (setq my-shell-reply nil) 
      (set-process-filter proc my-shell-exec-filter)
      (process-send-string proc "whatever...") 
      (if (not (accept-process-output proc my-shell-exec-timeout 100))
          (error "unexpected response."))

      ;; examine my-shell-reply here ...
```

Answer (score 2):

My final solution was:

```
(defun eval-all-sexps (s)
  (let ((s (concat gimme-filter-remainder s)))
    (setq gimme-filter-remainder
          (loop for x = (ignore-errors (read-from-string s))
                then (ignore-errors (read-from-string (substring s position)))
                while x
                summing (or (cdr x) 0) into position
                doing (eval (car x))
                finally (return (substring s position))))))
```